# Using Unicode characters in math mode with Bookdown (xelatex)

Tags: r, unicode, r-markdown, bookdown, xelatex

I try to use a Unicode character (U+2685) in math mode with Bookdown, I set `mathfont: STIX Two Math` (which contains this character), yet the resulting PDF contains an empty space. (At the same time the HTML is correct.)

What's wrong here?

(My best guess is that I should perhaps use the `unicode-math` package. Unfortunately I can't include it in the `preamble.tex` as it is [incompatible](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unicode-math.pdf) with the `mathspec`, but at the same time I see no way to get rid of `mathspec`; it seems to be hardcoded in Bookdown that `mathspec` is `usepackage`d when xelatex is used.)

Minimal reproducible example (showing `index.Rmd`, all other file is the same as with the default new project created with RStudio):

```
--- 
title: "A Minimal Book Example"
author: "Yihui Xie"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
link-citations: yes
description: "This is a minimal example of using the bookdown package to write a book. The output format for this example is bookdown::gitbook."
mainfont: STIX Two Math
mathfont: STIX Two Math
---

# Prerequisites

In text: ⚀.

In math mode: $⚀$.
```

This is how the result looks like:

[image]

Comment: Please add a [mre]

Comment: @samcarter Sorry for that, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is now solved (after an update to `rmarkdown`), see [here](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/810).